# In Pandora, how can I create a new station with the same seed as an existing station?

Tags: pandora

Sometimes I'll create a station in Pandora using a specific song as a seed. After some time, I will have up voted and down voted several songs. As a result, sometimes the station songs drift away from the initial seed I provided the station, and I would like to create a similar station which explores different attributes which are closer to the original song.

When I try creating a new station and choosing the same song as the seed, instead of creating a new station, it just takes me to the pre-existing station. I don't want to delete the old station, I want to have the old one and a new one which has no up votes and down votes. How can I do this in Pandora?

Answer (score 7):

There's also a slightly complex workaround to simply duplicate an entire station, including all upthumbs, downthumbs, and seeds:

1. Share the station with a friend. This allows the friend to access your station, but doesn't copy it.
2. Have the friend rename the station. This causes Pandora to give your friend their own copy of the station.
3. Have your friend share the new station with you. Now you have access to their copy of the station.
4. Rename the station you just got from your friend. This causes Pandora to make a new copy of it (again), and so now you have a second copy of the station.
5. Optionally, have your friend delete the station that they created in step 2.

Now you'll have two separate, independent copies of your station. Changing one station won't affect the other station. If you wish, you can delete all of the upthumbs and downthumbs from the new copy.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works.  You can't edit a shared station.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

There's no "duplicate station" feature. However, there's a slightly complex workaround to do what you want to do:

1. Hover the mouse the station that you want to duplicate, click on the small triangle on the right (if the station is playing, click on `Options`) then `Station details`
2. Look at *Track Seeds* list:

   - If there's just your original song, click `Add` and enter a song that is in your *Thumbed-up Tracks* list, then delete your original song (you can add it back again right after that - as long as it's not the first one in the list)
   - If there's more than one song, delete the song on the bottom (that's your original song)
3. You can now create a new station from that seed song

The key is to make sure that the seed song isn't the first one in the seed list because then Pandora turns on the station.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy:

1. Create a new station with a 'filler' song (anything at all)
2. Click 'add variety' on the new station and add the existing seed
   song
3. Delete the filler song

Presto, you now have a station with an identical seed.